# How to remove the strange border from shadow in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, css

See this fiddle in Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/qwbpZ/4/

On hover you will see this grey line

[image]

It's fine in Google Chrome but this grey border is appearing in other browsers. 
How can I solve this?

**CSS**

```
a, a:visited {color:#fff}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 9px 0 #000000, 0 13px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 9px 0 #000000, 0 13px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 9px 0 #000000, 0 13px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
  padding: 0px;
        background: black; /*  see ? */
}

.btn span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 22px 22px 11px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(19,65,88,.8);
  background: #2e2e2e;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
  color: #FFF;
        font-size: 32px;
        border: 0
}

.btn:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #000,
    0 12px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #000,
    0 12px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #000,
    0 12px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.btn:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -4px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -4px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -4px);
  transform: translate(0, -4px);
}

.btn:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #000,
    0 12px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #000,
    0 12px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #000,
    0 12px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
}
.btn:active span { 



  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0px);
  transform: translate(0, 0px);
}
```

Comment: Interestingly it looks fine in my Firefox (6.0.2) on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: It shows up for me, Firefox 6.0.2/Windows 7. @Thor84no: Did you hover on the button?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also compared it to Chrome (14.0.835.186), they look identical as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah, one of the fun points of composition and layering and the way antialiasing is implemented (being composed on the background colour rather than the actual layer behind). If no one else has written a satisfactory answer in a couple of days, I'll have time to fill it out... but there's no neat solution that I'm aware of (there's one messy one which occurs to me based on my knowledge of how it works which may work, but I'd need to try it to see if it does).

Comment: Happens in Opera 11.51 too.. kizu his solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems, that there is no perfect solution: this antiialiased pixels between shadow and border-radius are sticky as hell.

So, I came up with the following two solutions:

- Use an extra pseudo-element, that would underlay the problem place: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/qwbpZ/5/
- Add more extra black shadows (normal and inset): http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/qwbpZ/6/ — I've added here two, but there are still some pixels visible, if you'd add another two it'd be almost ok.

Sad, but these are not universal solutions and I couldn't find a proper way to fix the bug itself.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
-moz-background-clip: padding; 
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
 background-clip: padding-box;
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix: apply bottom and sides 1px black border to button.
Fixed button: http://jsfiddle.net/FJGeZ/2/
Notice box-shadow y-axis distance is less by 1px to compensate 1px bottom border, plus inner span with negative margins to overlap parent border.

Isolated bug here: http://jsfiddle.net/AkZE6/